# Spring. How to add same property to multiple beans?

Tags: java, spring

Consider I have something like this in beans.xml:

```
<bean id="emails" class="org.some.package.SomeClass">
  <property name="emailList">
  <list>
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
    <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

But I need to add emailList property into multiple beans. How can I do that without writing property to each bean? Can externalize property and inject it into each bean?

I expect something like:

```
<property name="commonProp">
  <list>
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
    <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
  </list>
</property>

<bean id="emailsOne" class="org.some.package.ClassOne">
  <property name="emailList" ref="commonProp" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailsTwo" class="org.some.package.ClassTwo">
  <property name="emailList" ref="commonProp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using: **util:list**

```
   <util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String"> 
      <value>foo</value> 
      <value>bar</value> 
   </util:list>
```

Then use this *myList* reference in other beans.